# Counting all Item class elements before and after header classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

Hey I am thinking of a Jquery solution to a problem. Below you can see I have items that follow after each heading now this is fine.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

But there are times when there will be no items. Just headers:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

In this case I would like to check if there are any items after each header. If there is none add paragraph text "Not Available" Like so:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<p>Not Available</p>
<div class="header"></div>
<p>Not Available</p>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Many Thanks for any help.

Comment: When do you add the header? and when do you add the items?

Comment: This is all added in a $.each and then at the end of the iteration I want to inspect what is left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works :

```
$('.header').filter(function(){
     return $(this).next().hasClass('header');
     // or return !$(this).next().hasClass('item');
}).after('<p>Not Available</p>')
```

Comment: That's the best way! But you should use `return !$(this).next().hasClass('item')` so it will also works for the last header. And using `after()` instead of `append()` will add the `p` after the header div as he asked (not in the header div)  :)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the solution.
return !$(this).next().hasClass('item'); is more preferred in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea for you:
 - You can add a class name groups to include the header class and the items class, like this:

```
<div class="groups">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="groups">
....
</div>
....
```

Now you have a lot of groups. What you have to do is count every group and check if item exist or not:

```
$('.groups').each(function(){
   if($(this).children('items').length > 0){
      // found items class
   }

   else{
      // not found any items class
      $(this).append('<p>Not Available</p>');
   }

});
```